# history.pushState - not working?

Tags: javascript, html, history, pushstate, pjax

I want to change html without reload. I do it like:

```
$('#left_menu_item').click(function(e) {
    if (!!(window.history && history.pushState)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        history.pushState(null, null, newUrl);
    }
});
```

It works correctly. But if I want to go back with "Back" button - browser change url on previous, but it not reload page. Why?

Comment: As far as I know the HTML5 history API doesn't actually modify page content .. I'm not even sure how the HTML is getting changed on pushState

Comment: what browser are you doing your experiment with? this kind of behaviour can have different results on different browsers

Comment: Chrome 24.0 & Firefox 17.0. Behaviours are same.

Comment: Answered your question.. Please let me know if that's what you had in mind.. Or if you wanted a more technical answer to your 'why' question

Answer (score 44, accepted):

this behaviour is expected and is in accordance with the [specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) of manipulating the history stack.

this is a relatively complex problem to explain. but in short think of it as this: any history entry the user pushes on the history stack (using pushState etc) doesn't merit a page load when you move from it because it is considered a fake (user generated) history entry.

**why?**
this behaviour is a good thing and is consistent with the intent of giving the developer more control over the page without being forced to reload it (think of it like ajax: you can do things that were previously only possible by page reloading like fetching data but now you can do it without reloading the page using the [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) object).. if you want to mimic the behaviour of reloading the page when clicking the back button.. you can simply call `location.reload()` when you handle the `window.onpopstate` event

---

**how?**
this may be outside the scope of your question but i just wanted to put it there to describe what we're talking about

let me explain by using an existing example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) (excerpted text will be *italicised*):

*Suppose http://mozilla.org/foo.html executes the following JavaScript:*

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

*This will cause the URL bar to display http://mozilla.org/bar.html, but won't cause the browser to load bar.html or even check that bar.html exists.*

think of it as that you are creating an entry in the history stack that is not associated with an actual page load.. rather a 'fake' page load (ie you are just using javascript to manipulate the dom and insert html)..

*Suppose now that the user now navigates to http://google.com, then clicks back. At this point, the URL bar will display http://mozilla.org/bar.html, and the page will get a popstate event whose state object contains a copy of stateObj. The page itself will look like foo.html, although the page might modify its contents during the popstate event.*

the point here is that bar.html is a fake history entry that sits on top of the original http://mozilla.org/foo.html.. so you will see on the url http://mozilla.org/bar.html but the contents will belong to foo (in this example notice that we didnt manipulate the content of the dom when we pushed bar.html.. if we did like in your example.. then that content will also show up). the key thing here is that the page **reloads!**.. because we are serving a page that has a genuin entry on the history stack (even if on the url.. we are displaying a url that is associated with a fake entry on the history stack).

also separate this discussion from the page manually handling the popstate event.. that's a different story and will just complicate things.

*If we click back again, the URL will change to http://mozilla.org/foo.html, and the document will get another popstate event, this time with a null state object. Here too, going back doesn't change the document's contents from what they were in the previous step, although the document might update its contents manually upon receiving the popstate event.*

here.. the page **will not load!**.. that's because we are making the transfer from a fake history stack entry to the real one (and the real one was already loaded in the previous step.. so the page reloaded and that's it).

that's it for the example. the concept is kind of hard to explain and i encourage you to test your code by clicking through a combination of real and fake pages and you will see a pattern of when the page actually loads and when it doesn't..

Answer (score 15):

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {    
    if(event && event.state) {
        location.reload(); 
    }
}
```

This is what I use :)

Comment: or use window.location = window.location;