# event.state== null and How to get pushState run correctly at Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pushstate, html5-history

```
$('.btn').click(function(event){
  var paged = $(this).attr("id");
  history.pushState(paged, "", event.target.href);
  $.ajax({
    do something
  }
});
});
window.onpopstate = function(event) {alert(event.state); };
```

Use Chrome, Safari, Firefox to check it,

only Chrome and Safari can show the alert (message = paged) when the back button is clicked, but Firefox shows null value for the alert message,

and thus, I cannot use onpopstate to load a previous page content to Firefox when the back button is clicked. Then how to solve it or push the event.state correctly, but not a null value for firefox :)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [history.pushState - not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824766/history-pushstate-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here: https://lazyfox.io/task/b8r/event-state-null-and-how-to-get-pushstate-run-correctly-at-firefox

> Browsers used to handle the popstate event differently on page load, but now they behave the same. Firefox never emitted a popstate event on page load. Chrome did until version 34, while Safari did until version 10.0.
>
> You may have got null when history go back to the initial state.
>
> Though firefox won't push the initail state, you can still force Firefox to push the initial state with history.replaceState() call.

See the link for more details